# get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

No entiendo por que pasa este tipo de errores, muchas veces me salta ese error y me dice que se han pasado mas argumentos de la cuenta, muchas veces pasas aunque no solo con **get_queryset** sino también con otros metodos

Esta es mi vista:

```
class BussinesInformationView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = BussinesInformationSerializer
    
    def get_permissions(self):
        authentication_classes = TokenAuthentication
        permission_classes = [Is_partner, IsAuthenticated]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    
    def get_queryset(self):
        #Restrict list to only user 
        queryset = BussinesInformation.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset

     
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = BussinesInformationSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": self.request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        information = serializer.save()
        data = BussinesInformationSerializer(information).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bussines/', BussinesInformationView.as_view({'post':'create', 'get':'get_queryset'})),
]
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError at /bussines/
get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/bussines/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error no está en ese código que colocaste. En algún sitio tienes una instancia de `BussinesInformationView` y estás llamando al método `get_queryset` pasando un parámetro que no es requerido (el `self` se va llenar con la instancia con la que hagas la llamada) así que la llamada solo debería ser:

```
instancia.get_queryset()
```